# Why does this relation $\sum ^{k}_{n=m} f( n) =\int\limits ^{k+1}_{m} f(\lfloor x\rfloor ) dx$ not apply here?

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I have this relation
$\sum ^{k}_{n=m} f( n) =\int\limits ^{k+1}_{m} f(\lfloor x\rfloor ) dx$

I have used this relation before and it was correct in every situation I tried except for this

$\int\limits ^{k}_{0}\lfloor sin( x)\rfloor dx=\sum ^{k-1}_{n=0} sin( n) =\frac{1}{2}\left( cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) cos( k) -sin( k)\right)$

I found this to be completely incorrect! I have no idea why the relation doesn't work here.  Any insight will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Because $\lfloor\sin(x) \rfloor \neq \sin(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ (the LHS is always an integer, the RHS not necessarily)

Comment: @peek-a-boo So $\lfloor f( x)\rfloor =f(\lfloor x\rfloor )$ for the relation to work?

Comment: The relation is true always.  You are misapplying it to an integrand of the form $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$.  That's all.

Comment: @Brian Moehring Oh! Thank you! (edit) The relation I used doesn't seem to work when $k+1$ isn't an integer.  Maybe the same for $m$.  Is that because the formula that replaces the series was derived based on the fact that the sum's limits would be whole numbers?

Comment: Yes, both $m$ and $k$ need to be integers (or $\pm\infty$) and $m\leq k$.